# Terraform key does not identify an element in this collection

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm following a [terraform tutorial on using variables in AWS](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-variables?in=terraform/aws-get-started).

It defines AMI variables like:

```
variable "amis" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "us-east-1" = "ami-b374d5a5"
    "us-west-2" = "ami-fc0b939c"
  }
}
```

And then assigns the AMI variable like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = var.amis[var.region]
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

If I try the example that way I get an error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 17, in resource "aws_instance" "example":
  17:   ami                    = var.amis[var.region]

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string
required.
```

However I can set the variable by hard coding it:

```
var.amis["us-west-2"] # <-- this works
```

What can I do to set the variable correctly with `ami           = var.amis[var.region]` ?

Comment: Is `var.region` defined and one of your keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define variable `var.region` or you can pass the value to variable during plan / apply as `terraform plan -var 'region=us-west-2'` and `terraform apply -var 'region=us-west-2'`